# Adding plots to different figures using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

for a particular purpose, I want to plot 2-3 different figures using `matplotlib` and add different graphs to each of these figures. My particular requirement is complex and hard to explain, so I will try to explain with a simpler example.

For example, imagine I have a list of signals called 
`[signal_1,signal_2,signal_3, .... , signal _40]`
where each 'signal_XXX' represents a numpy-array, some of length 5000 and other length 10,000.

I want to plot all these signals in 2 different graphs, depending on their length.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
my_signals = [ signal_1,signal_2,....,signal_40]

fig_5000 = plt.figure(1)

fig_10000 = plt.figure(2)

for signal_i in my_signals :
    if len(signal_i) == 5000 :
        fig_5000.plot(signal_i)
    if len(signal_i) == 10000 :
        fig_10000.plot(signal_i)

# now I want to individually show these 2 figures
fig_5000.show()
" do something else here "
fig_10000.show()
```

Obviously the code which I wrote will not work, also on the last part if I use
`plt.show()` both graphs will show at the same time, which I don't want.

Is there any way to do the stuff which I want to do using matplotlib ? or should I try something else?

**EDIT**

I include a 'working' code , with suggestion from Diziet Asahi,

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
my_signals = []
for i in range (0,25):
    if i//2 == 0 :
        my_signals.append( numpy.random.rand(100))
    if i//2 == 1 :
        my_signals.append( numpy.random.rand(200))
"""numpy.random.rand craetes an array with random numbers of the given shape.
now we have  a list of 50 arrays with 100 and 200 lengths """

fig_100 = plt.figure(1)
ax100 = fig_100.add_subplot(111)
plt.title(" length = 100")
fig_200 = plt.figure(2)
plt.title(" length = 200")
ax200 = fig_200.add_subplot(111)


for arrayzz in my_signals :
    if len(arrayzz) == 100 :
        ax100.plot(arrayzz)
    if len(arrayzz) == 200:
        ax200.plot(arrayzz)

plt.show()
```

This fixes the first part of the earlier problem. Still, I can't show them individually.

Comment: Would you mind correcting the grammar, spelling,capitalization in your question and its title?

Comment: `"Obviously the code which I wrote will not work'` - you should explain why it doesn't work so *we* don't have to run it and find out for *ourselves*.

Comment: Can you make a Minimal Reproducible Example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) i.e. make the code you post actually work.

Comment: Because the ` 'Figure' object has no attribute 'plot'`, so we can't specify to which figure the plot should go by the way I attempted.

Comment: [Multiple Figs Demo](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/multiple_figs_demo.html) ... [Working with multiple figures and axes-tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html#working-with-multiple-figures-and-axes)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotting on multiple figures with subplots in a single loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46573570/plotting-on-multiple-figures-with-subplots-in-a-single-loop)

Comment: That question doesn't answer my second question, that is to show the 2 graphs individually.@wwii

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to creating *figures* you also need to create *axes*. You don't say if you want all your signals to be on the same axes, but generally this should do the trick:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
my_signals = [ signal_1,signal_2,....,signal_40]

fig_5000 = plt.figure(1)
ax_5000 = fig_5000.add_subplot(111)

fig_10000 = plt.figure(2)
ax_10000 = fig_10000.add_subplot(111)

for signal_i in my_signals :
    if len(signal_i) == 5000 :
        ax_5000.plot(signal_i)
    if len(signal_i) == 10000 :
        ax_10000.plot(signal_i)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks your answer fixed the first part of my question. Can you also tell me how to display both these figures one-by-one ? `plt.show()` will plot both the figures at the same time...

Comment: For anyone who gets confused by seeing `subplot` being used, let me inform you that the figures get plotted in two separate windows.

Answer (score 1):

There is no good solution for this currently. `plt.show()` shows all open pyplot figures. You can of course close anyThe problem is essentially the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729948/matplotlib-how-to-show-a-figure-that-has-been-closed), and of course writing your own GUI for the figure, showing it whenever you want is possible, but cumbersome.

There is an idea to enhance the `show` function in a future version, see https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/14024, but for now the solution would be

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def reshow(fig):
    import importlib
    import matplotlib.backends
    import matplotlib.backend_bases
    backend_mod = importlib.import_module(f"matplotlib.backends.backend_{plt.get_backend().lower()}")
    Backend = type("Backend", (matplotlib.backends._Backend,), vars(backend_mod))
    fm = Backend.new_figure_manager_given_figure(1, fig)
    matplotlib.backend_bases.Gcf.set_active(fm)
    plt.show()


my_signals = []
for i in range (0,25):
    if i//2 == 0 :
        my_signals.append( numpy.random.rand(100))
    if i//2 == 1 :
        my_signals.append( numpy.random.rand(200))


fig_100 = plt.figure(1)
ax100 = fig_100.add_subplot(111)
ax100.set_title(" length = 100")

fig_200 = plt.figure(2)
ax200 = fig_200.add_subplot(111)
ax200.set_title(" length = 200")

for arrayzz in my_signals :
    if len(arrayzz) == 100 :
        ax100.plot(arrayzz)
    if len(arrayzz) == 200:
        ax200.plot(arrayzz)

# First close all figures
plt.close("all")
#Then (re)show a single figure
reshow(fig_100)
# and the other one
reshow(fig_200)
```

Comment: Hi, when I try to execute your code I'm getting the following error.   ```ImportError: No module named backend_{plt.get_backend().lower()} ```

Comment: Oh, which python version are you using?